# who does the method call it self again after the return?

Tags: javascript, recursion, depth-first-search

In the last method dfs(), after the node will be '1' the two if statement will not go into and it will go until the return statement without any line that call the method again, !!!but it call it self again!!!
who does that come?

I'm using JS.

Here is the code with online compiler: https://repl.it/repls/EnchantingSpanishBlockchain

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
  }
  insert(value) {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    if (this.root === null) {
      this.root = newNode;
    } else {
      let currentNode = this.root;
      while (true) {
        if (value < currentNode.value) {
          //Left
          if (!currentNode.left) {
            currentNode.left = newNode;
            return this;
          }
          currentNode = currentNode.left;
        } else {
          //Right
          if (!currentNode.right) {
            currentNode.right = newNode;
            return this;
          }
          currentNode = currentNode.right;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function dfs(node, list) {
  if (node.left) {
    dfs(node.left, list);
  }
  if (node.right) {
    dfs(node.right, list);
  }
  list.push(node.value);
  return list;
}
//      9
//  4      20
//1   6  15   170  
const tree = new BinarySearchTree();
tree.insert(9)
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(20)
tree.insert(170)
tree.insert(15)
tree.insert(1)
//DFTPostOrder
console.log(dfs(tree.root, []));
```

Comment: This is called `Recursion`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion

Comment: When it reaches node 1 it doesn't call itself again. What makes you think it does?

Comment: The only calls to `dfs` are the one at the end of the script and the two within it. Your best bet for understanding how this recursive function works is to step through it in the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser. Be sure to watch the Call Stack. Note that `dfs` may call itself (recursion), and that call may call itself again (more recursion), etc., possibly several calls deep, which may be what's confusing you.